# flatMap (word, (song, another_song)) to rdd

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, flatmap

I have a rdd with this structure:

```
[('song1', 'artist1', ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word1']), 
('song2', 'artist2', ['word1', 'word3', 'word1'])]
```

Where I want map every word that appears with the different songs, for example:

```
('word1', ('song1', 'song2')), ('word2', ('song1')), ('word3', ('song1', 'song2'))
```

What I have tried is the following using flatMap and reduceByKey:

```
rdd_songs = rdd.map(lambda x: [(word, x[0]) for word in x[2]]).flatMap(lambda x: x).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

The output is what I want but not exactly doing this:

```
[('word1', 'song1song1song2'), ('word2', 'song1'), ('word3', 'song1song2')
```

I was told to that the flatMapValues function would be useful but also can't seem to understand the method, very well, any help would be very helpful

Comment: something like this? `rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(word, x[0]) for word in x[2]]).groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: tuple(set(x))).collect()`

Comment: YES, thanks a lot, exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).